# How to find a substring in a cell array

Tags: regex, string, matlab, cell-array

I am trying to use regexp in MATLAB to search for two words in strings in cell arrays. My cell array contains

```
strings={'1abc_2def_ghi_AB_12A','1abc_2def_ghi_BD_19A','1abc_2def_ghi_CD_16A',}
```

How would I go about constructing the expression to search the cell array for the string that contains both `'ghi'` and `'12'`?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Where is your problem implementing this? Finding a matching regular expression or iterating the cell?

Comment: My problem is finding a matching regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
result = find(~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(strings, 'ghi')) & ...
    ~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(strings, 'AB')));
```

Or, using a single regular expression,

```
result = find(~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(strings, '(ghi.*AB|ghi.*AB)')));
```